# Group of order 7*11*19 has a normal subgroup of order 11 or order 19

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Is this correct?

This group has Sylow subgroups of order 7, 11 and 19.
It is easy to see that $n_7=1$.
Also $n_{11}=1$ or $n_{11}=7*19$ and $n_{19}=1$ or $n_{19}=7*11$. 
To show that group of order 7*11*19 has normal subgroup of order 11 or order 19, it is enough to show that $n_{11}=7*19$ and $n_{19}=7*11$ can not hold in the same time, i.e. either one of $n_{11}$ and $n_{19}$ is 1. 
Suppose that none of them is 1. This means there are 7*19=133 cyclic 11-Sylow subgroups of order 11 and 7*11=77 cyclic 19-Sylow subgroups of order 19. Elements in 11-Sylow groups are all, except $e$, of order 11.
Elements in 19-Sylow groups are all, except $e$, of order 19.
This means there are 133*10=1330 elements of order 11 and 77*18=1386 elements of order 19, but group has $1463<1330+1386$ elements, which gives us a contradiction. So, either $n_{11}=1$ or $n_{19}=1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. Now go on to show that actually it has normal subgroups of both orders and hence is cyclic.

Comment: Thanks.Are you sure both $n_i$ are 1? I think just one of them has to be 1. @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You cannot see this directly from the Sylow theorems like this. But remember that you already have shown that the group has a normal subgroup of order $7$. What happens in the quotient by this?